# What is the difference between Images folder and images sub-folder inside Content folder in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I was wondering if someone could help me by letting me know the difference between Images folder and images sub-folder inside Content folder in mvc4?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's up to you  as long as you are consistent where you want images. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575640/is-the-content-folder-sacred-in-asp-net-mvc