# what is the purpose of a css link placed like this style.css?23409823098

Tags: css

Duplicate of [what does do in a css link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link)

I've seen a few sites who list a stylesheet with parameters in it.
does anyone know what its called and what purpose they serve?

ex:

href="fonts.css?1169659562000"

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link

Answer (score 3):

The parameter is changed every time the content of the file changes. This allows the site hoster to set an infinite cache timeout, which keeps the browser from re-requesting the CSS. Without the parameter, updates would never reach the client.

See also the [Stackoverflow Podcast #38](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/podcast-38/) and the [YSlow tool](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

Answer (score 2):

To force the browser to refresh the CSS link.  It's more reliable than expires headings and the like.