# Stylesheet fails to load on first request after deployment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

After a new version of the site is deployed, the first time every user opens the site, none of the site's stylesheets are downloaded or load. Refreshing the page downloads and loads the stylesheets and then the site looks fine until the next time we do a deployment.

The site is a .NET 4 MVC website deployed to Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS 7. The site is deployed using a publish package created through VS10 and imported into IIS.

Most users access the site using IE10 or 11 and some earlier IE users. None of the pcs available to test on have Firefox or Chrome, so I haven't been able to test whether the site's styles show up on first load in other browsers. Locally, the site displays correctly regardless of the browser and version used. There are no server errors or browser errors reported.

The styles are Bootstrap, and a custom site stylesheet.

Comment: I believe it's a duplicate of this question:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239907/can-i-force-a-refresh-of-my-stylesheet-file

Comment: I've tried that solution (adding timestamp or ticks to the reference URL) without success.

Answer (score 0):

Is the CSS reference rendering into the page source correctly? We have had similar issues with our .Net 4.0 CMS where dynamically populated references failed to populate under load because the response was getting flushed before update. Unfortunately we had to revert to static reference in master pages due to time constraints.

Comment: The CSS references look identical in the source of the page whether the styles render or not.

Comment: Can you access the style sheet directly after a deploy? Can you run failed request tracing or capture a failed page load in FireFox with FireBug?

Comment: I can access the stylesheet directly immediately after a deploy. Can't access the site from any pc with FireFox, and can't install FireFox on the pcs I do have access to.