# CSS files that have numbers in their query string?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ‘?’ do in a Css link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link)

```
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css?1268721265" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css?1268721265" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Why does the css file URL have **1268721265** in it?

Any ideas? Thanks.