# Primefaces static resources served from apache

Tags: apache, jsf, primefaces, jboss, staticresource

I have an application using Primefaces 6.1, JSF 2.1, running on JBoss EAP 7.1. In front of Jboss there is an apache and i want that this resolve the static resource and not delegate it to Jboss. I create a /nas/ folder where i put my static resource but how i can put there the resources generate by the primefaces that automatically primefaces put on the resource path when the .xhtml page needs it  (/contexPath/javax.faces.resource/component.js?ln=primefaces&v=6.1)?

Comment: in JSF you can intercept many aspects. Maybe you can extract the resources from PF source and place them on your Apache. Then extend the ResourceHandlerWrapper and intercept PF related resource URLs to point to the static server. A little bit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268345/how-can-i-implement-css-versioning-to-solve-cache-issues-using-jsf-2-houtpu/6842735#6842735

Comment: It's easier to configure Apache to cache them on its own.

Comment: @BalusC Also if apache cache i continue to see log on access log of Jboss, also if they log a 304 response.