# What is the purpose of "?9" when pointing to CSS?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does '?' do in a Css link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link)

Some website pointing to static CSS files with `?9` at the end:

```
<link href="http://www.site.com/css/style.css?9" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I can easily understand if that file is PHP file, but I dont know what is the purpose of putting `?9` at the end of the href to a static CSS file.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's a version number. Static resources such as CSS are cached by client browsers. So by simply modifying the version browsers will refetch the new CSS there are updates. StackOverflow uses similar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=ef2f2383c884">
```

Answer (score 3):

The `?9` might be to prevent reading from cache by the browser. It's used when loading dynamic content from a static file, like so:

```
changingListOfStuff.txt?randomUselessPropertyToTrickBrowser=123456789
```

This forces the browser to use this exact file, not a cached version of `changingListOfStuff.txt` previously downloaded and stored by the browser. Caching speeds up loading time, but might provide an older version of the file if it changes rapidly.

Read more about caching here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache