# Simple question about style sheet source files [*.css?ver=]

Tags: css

What does appending a query string to the end of a style sheet do? I often see:

```
some-stylesheet.css?ver=1.2.3
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does '?' do in a Css link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link)

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock...I am sure its a duplicate. I did a search before posting my Q but my search argument yielding nothing relevant

Comment: All answers (essentially) relate to caching. I plan to accept @BraedenP's answer because it was the first one posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people use it to prevent caching of the CSS file.

It could also be used by the server software (Apache, for example) to load a specific version of the CSS based on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a new query string forces the browser to reload the file instead of using a cached one.

Answer (score 0):

it helps with caching, if you append a query string the browser treats it like a new file, that way when you make changes they are shown immediately, not after you clear the browser cache

Answer (score 0):

This is used in order to workaround browser caching while developing. If you increment that number in your HTML, browser will suppose it's a new file that he has not see ever before and will render the last version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Problably they want to show you the newest version of the CSS, without caché of the browser. So using a parameter its solved.

Comment: Caché does not mean what you think it means. I know, I'm being picky, but it's irritating.