# Parameter on <img> tag

Tags: html

I found that some website use parameters on image `src` like `?v=1390510765392`

what is it used for ?

```
<img src="image.jpg?v=1390510765392" />
```

Found on [that](http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/lazy-src-angularjs/) Angularjs example

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397942/why-querystrings-after-images-css-files

Comment: The duplicate gets 2 upvote Im getting 2 downvote ahahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possible uses...

1. If the parameter randomly changes every time the page is loaded, then it's a common means of preventing the browser from caching the image.  This would force the browser to always request a new one (because the URL is different) so that the user always has the latest version.
2. If `image.jpg` isn't actually an image but rather a code-driven server-side resource which *responds* with an image, then URL parameters would be a way to pass an identifier to that resource to identify which specific image data to download.  (Such as if the images, or at least references to them, are stored in a database.)

The first one is very likely what's happening here, though the second is certainly possible.

Comment: I use technique #1 with CSS background images which are generally cached more aggressively than HTML images (depending on the browser).

Answer (score 2):

The `src` attribute of the element is simply passing the `GET` variable `v` to the server at the `image.jpg` endpoint with a value of `1390510765392`. Without examining the server-side code, it is unclear why the developer is doing this. A few possibilities come to mind:

- `image.jpg` could actually be a script (or interpreted by one) despite the `.jpg` extension, in which case it is possible that `1390510765392` is a resource token used to retrieve a specific image.
- A frequent use of such a parameter is to simply change the `src` attribute without actually changing what it points at, thus invalidating any client-side (or intermediary) cache of the image and forcing it to reload, in which case the server itself likely ignores `v`.

Answer (score 1):

It allows for the name of the image to remain the same but by appending the query string it prevents browsers from using a cached version of the image. The query string essentially makes the URL "new" so the browser goes and gets what it believes to be a new resource.

Comment: I think calling it the "version number" is a little misleading.

Comment: Only a little if at all. But since that part is not important I have removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to avoid image to be served from browser cache (because the URL is different if date changes and it makes no effect on images)

Answer (score 0):

Another possabilty is to avoid flushing CDN resources when the image changes preventing the user from seeing an old version if the image.