# ASp.NEt MVC :Push new Resources updates of website in web browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have developed my website using ASP.MVC3 platform, please provide exact solution for below concerns.

If User visit my website After new resource  updates[style changes,script] in our site, they can view  only old resources in website .
For getting new resource updates in site they need to manually refresh the page several times for get it to render properly with new changes. This doesn't happen on any  several sites.

SO anyone suggest How to avoid refresh the page again and again for getting new updates site in programmatical way. and also suggest any possibility to do this in my site global.axjax file MVC application while website loading?

Please don't tell like this  "clear your browser cache "

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common technique people use is to update the reference to the source files by adding random query string in the end of link,  like this

```
<link href="/Content/all.min.css?d=20090107" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

you can do the same for Javascript files. For more details on why this helps, check the following link

[What does '?' do in a Css link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438821/what-does-do-in-a-css-link/438828#438828)